# Multiple Columns into One by one row in sql and count of those values

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
User  |  Acc1 | Acc2 |  Acc3 |  Acc4
_____________________________________    
1     |  BB   |  B   |    CC |   AA    
1     |  AA   | CC   |    B  |       
1     |  BB   | CC   |    AA |
```

Desired Output :

```
User | Acc |  Count    
1    | BB  |  2    
1    | B   |  2    
1    | AA  |  3    
1    | CC  |  3
```

I Want a Query For My Output

Comment: How many "AccX" column you have? Is the number dynamic?

Comment: I have Four AccX Columns. Not Dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

```
select user, acc, sum(cnt) as count
from
(
    select user, acc1 as acc, count(*) as cnt from your_table group by acc1
    union all
    select user, acc2, count(*) from your_table group by acc2
    union all
    select user, acc3, count(*) from your_table group by acc3
    union all
    select user, acc4, count(*) from your_table group by acc4
) tmp
group by user, acc
```

Comment: You need to `select` and `group by` the `User` column too.

Comment: User_Code     Person_Code  Person1    Person2   Person4
USC00000433   AA           AAA         A        B
USC00000433   B            A           AA
USC00000433   AAA          B           A        AA   Actually this is my real table. From Your Answer I Cant Understand Where i can get 'ACC' column name From table

Comment: Please update the question. I can't read that comment without formatting.

Comment: Oh Sorry For Inconvenience. I Got The Output As Per Your Guidance. Thanks Lot. Hope You Will Help Me For My Future Doubts Too.

Comment: One More Doubt.. If i am having NULL value in the columns(For Ex : I am Having 'Null' in the place Of 'CC') means I shouldn't get the count of the null values in my output??? Can u help me for this ?

Comment: No, `null` values do not count.